# C Multithreading nested for loops - problem of combinatorial explosion from hyperparameter grid search

Tags: c, multithreading, combinatorics, hyperparameters

I have a small C program with less than 500 lines of code. Here is a simplified version. The actual one is more compute intensive.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int array_a [100000000];
// array 382 MB in size, 100 million x 4 bytes

int main(void)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 1000; a++)
        {
        for (int b = 0; b < 1000; b++)
            {
            for (int c = 0; c < 1000; c++)
                {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
                    {
                    int x = array_a[i] + a + b + c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
return 0;
}
```

Right now I do manual multithreading for my 4-core cpu where I compile 4 different versions of the code. Using the example above, each process would then use 400 MB of ram, for a total of 1.6 GB ram usage.

I need to change just two numbers in the first for loop for the 4 different compilations:

```
compile 1: for (int a = 0; a < 250; a++)
compile 2: for (int a = 250; a < 500; a++)
compile 3: for (int a = 500; a < 750; a++)
compile 4: for (int a = 750; a < 1000; a++)
```

Very easy solution.

I've been trying to figure out pthreads, but I can't wrap my head around it. My code doesn't use functions and pointers.

How would you split the code above into 25 threads?

```
thread 1: (int a = 0; a < 40; a++)
thread 2: (int a = 40; a < 80; a++)
....
thread 24: (int a = 920; a < 960; a++)
thread 25: (int a = 960; a < 1000; a++)
```

Is each thread going to use 400 MB for the array (total 10 GB ram usage)? Or is each thread going to use the same 400 MB of ram (total 400 MB ram usage)? I don't care about ram usage, just the fastest solution.

Comment: How about forgetting pthreads and looking into [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) instead. You're not doing *threading* as such, just parallel calculations.

Comment: Additionally... you've got 4 CPUs so 25 threads is an overkill

Comment: As long as the loop limit can be divided evenly by the number of threads, then it's easy to calculate the ranges, use a structure for those ranges (i.e. starting index and the number of iterations to make) and also have that structure contain a pointer to the first element of your array. Then pass that structure to the thread.

Comment: As for memory usage, processes on POSIX systems *duplicates* the memory of the parent process (even through it commonly uses copy-on-write for efficiency), while in a multi-threaded process all threads *share* the same memory.

Answer (score 2):

There's [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) which provides an API for parallelisation.

If you want to do it manually with pthreads etc, you have to put the loops in a thread callback, then pass each thread the `a` min and max values as it's individual job order. They can all access the array simultaneously as long as no thread overwrites the memory area used by another thread.

You'll have to benchmark the code and see how many threads that are ideal, since thread creation comes with overhead code.